# SQL Select data and if loop

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I must SELECT and JOIN data from tables. For example I have table:

```
PRODUCTS: id | productName

PRICES: id | idProduct | price1

PRICES_GROUPS: id | idProduct | price2
```

When idProducts exist on table PRICES_GROUPS I must get "price2" when not exist I must get "price1" from tabel PRICES

I use mySQL. Any idea to solution this problem?

Comment: Two LEFT JOIN and COALESCE().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you case you can try

```
select p.*,COALESCE(pg.price2,pc.price1) as price from PRODUCTS p left join PRICES_GROUPS pg on pg.idProduct = p.id left join PRICES pc on pc.idProduct = p.id;
```